# sed replace text containing new line

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script for installing a web server on my Ubuntu server.

I'd like, in the /etc/apache2/apache2.conf, to replace

```
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

#
```

by

```
#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"
ServerName localhost

#
```

If I do

```
sed -i 's|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"\nServerName localhost|' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

it's working, but I'd like to include the blank line and the # after the #ServerRoot to avoid adding twice ServerName if the script is executed twice.

I tried

```
sed -i 's|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"\n\n#|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"\nServerName localhost\n\n#|' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

1. search for `#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"`
2. if found, read and append the next line into sed's pattern space
3. search the appended pattern space for an empty line after the newline, and substitute `ServerName localhost` for *that*

Putting that together,

```
sed -i '\|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"| {N;s|\n$|\nServerName localhost|}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

In case the 'empty' line actually contains whitespace, you could modify that to

```
sed -i '\|#ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"| {N;s|\n\s*$|\nServerName localhost|}' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Comment: Another solution working is the one of muru - see above - but out of context because not using sed.

Comment: What is that `\` at the beginning of the `sed` command? Is the command the same as `sed -i '/regex/ s/the/rest/' filename`?

Comment: @AlaaAli sorry, I don't see any ` (backtick) character - perhaps it is an artifact of how your browser is rendering the page?

Comment: Oh sorry, something went wrong with my comment. I meant: What is that \ at the beginning of the `sed` command? Is the command the same as `sed -i '/regex/ s/the/rest/' filename`?

Comment: The leading `\\` just tells sed to use the following character as its delimiter - see for example the [Addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Addresses) section from the GNU sed manual.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the double-`\n` checking working in `sed` with help [from this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n). Bit of a mouthful:

```
sed -Ei ':a;N;$!ba;s/^(#ServerRoot[^\n]*)\n\n/\1\nServerName localhost\n\n/' apache2.conf
```

And an awk that does the same (longer but easier to understand IMO). The logic and `sponge` are explained in the last section.

```
awk '{print}/^#ServerRoot/{getline; if($0=="") print "ServerName localhost"; print}' apache2.conf | sponge apache2.conf
```

---

Edit: The `sed` isn't as hard as I originally thought it was. You just want to match and append (the `a` command); you don't need to replace. I've tested the following as working:

```
sed -i '/^#ServerRoot/a ServerName localhost' apache2.conf
```

You can be more specific with your match if you wish and I'll leave the `awk` below for posterity's sake.

---

The editing is fairly trivial with `awk` but in order to write back into the same file we either need a temporary intermediary file or `sponge` (from the `moreutils` package). I'll show both methods.

```
awk '{print}/^#ServerRoot/{print "ServerName localhost"}' apache2.conf > tmp
mv tmp apache2.conf
```

Or

```
awk '{print}/^#ServerRoot/{print "ServerName localhost"}' apache2.conf | sponge apache2.conf
```

The `awk` is just printing every line it finds but in the case of a match for `^#ServerName` is then writes your ServerName line. I find this sort of processing a lot easier to read than arbitrary "swapping" with sed.

Comment: Ok, but it's not resolving the problem that if you execute the script twice, the ServerName line will be added twice.

Comment: @tweetysat add a grep check. Better still, use the conf-available folder and create a file.

Comment: @muru I tried your solution creating a file in conf-available.  It's working fine.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (thanks muru) but a little out of context because not using sed :

For **Ubuntu 14.04**:

Create a file  **fqdn.conf** dans **/etc/apache2/conf-available/** containing

```
ServerName localhost
```

Create a symbolic link in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/conf-available/fqdn.conf /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/fqdn.conf
```